# How do I save documents to the gallery? - Swift

Tags: swift

I transform the images contained in the UIImage array into gifs and save them in the simulator's files. How can I save it on the phone's gallery instead?

```
extension UIImage {
    static func animatedGif(from images: [UIImage]) {
        let fileProperties: CFDictionary = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]  as CFDictionary
        let frameProperties: CFDictionary = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String): 1.0]] as CFDictionary

        let documentsDirectoryURL: URL? = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let fileURL: URL? = documentsDirectoryURL?.appendingPathComponent("animated.gif")

        if let url = fileURL as CFURL? {
            if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, kUTTypeGIF, images.count, nil) {
                CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties)
                for image in images {
                    if let cgImage = image.cgImage {


                        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, cgImage, frameProperties)
                    }
                }
                if !CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination) {
                    print("Failed to finalize the image destination")
                }
                print("Url = \(fileURL)")
            }
        }
    }
}

  override func viewDidLoad() {
               super.viewDidLoad()

 UIImage.animatedGif(from: [UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "secilmemisstep"), UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "secilmisstep"), UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "secilmemisstep")])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum).